# fflush(stdin) does not work compiled with gcc in cygwin but does compiled with visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, cygwin, fflush

I am (re-)learning programming and I started with C. My IDE (if I may say so) is cygwin (32Bit) and Visual-Studio 2010 both on Windows7.
I am always compiling the code I write with gcc (cygwin) as well as with the VS2010 compiler. I do so, I guess, because I think it is a good way of learning.
Anyway I just learned about fflush(stdin), i.e. flushing the stdin buffer. Seems a good functionality because else, using scanf appears to be a pain.
So I wrote the code below based on an example from my text book. It compiles both with gcc in cygwin as well as with VS2010. When I run the VS compiled program it works fine (s.below), when I run the gcc compiled program in cygwin the fflush(stdin) does not flush the stdin buffer (s.below).
I have read some threads about fflush(stdin) having an undefined behaviour in some cases. Whatever that may mean, I took it from the C for Linux Programming textbook. If fflush(stdin) is not a valid means to get rid of stuff in the stdin buffer, what other standard method is there?

Thanks a lot for any answers!

==Program run under Windows:

```
enter a long integer and a double
23.00 78.99
lint = 23
dt = 0.00

enter a five digits input
78493
u entered 78 and 493
```

==Program run in Cygwin:

```
enter a long integer and a double
23.00 78.99
lint = 23
dt = 0.00

enter a five digits input
u entered 78 and 2665720
```

==CODE====

```
long lint;
double dt;
int fp, sp;
char fn[50], ln[50];

/* using the l modifier to enter long integers and doubles */
puts ("enter a long integer and a double");
scanf("%ld %lf", &lint, &dt);

printf("lint = %d\ndt = %.2f\n", lint, dt);

fflush(stdin); /*DOES NOT WORK UNDER CYGWIN!?*/

/* use field width to split input */

puts("\nenter a five digits input");
scanf("%2d %3d", &fp, &sp);

printf("u entered %d and %d\n", fp, sp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C11 at 7.21.5.2.2 says (emphasis mine):

> If `stream` points to **an output stream** or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

This means that you shouldn't call `fflush` on an input stream (unless you are writing code for a very specific operating system and library where the behavior is defined)

There is a good reason for it! You would normally think that `fflush(stdin)` would flush the line you have just entered, right? Well there's more to it. Imagine running your program like this:

```
$ ./program < input_file
```

In this case, all the file is theoretically already in the buffer of `stdin`. Therefore, flushing that buffer equals ending your input which is quite a useless operation. For such reasons, `fflush` cannot have a very sensible behavior on input streams and that's why it's undefined on them.

---

If you want to ignore the current line, there are better ways to do it. One example is the following:

```
void flush_line(FILE *fin)
{
    int c;
    do
    {
        c = fgetc(fin);
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

This reads the input character by character and stops until either end-of-file, read error or end-of-line occurs.

Answer (score 2):

In the standard, fflush() is not defined for input streams.  In [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it is explicitly defined.

The upshot is that while you can use it with Microsoft's C library with clearly defined behaviour, such behaviour is not portable.

If you want to use GCC and have this work, then you could use MinGW/GCC since that uses Microsoft's C runtime rather than glibc.

Comment: +1 thanks that works. Why does fflush(stdin) work but flushall() doesn't work?  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ipcfQfRD

Comment: @barlop : I had to follow your link to discover that by "not working" you mean "not linking".  In the context of this question, it was a reasonable assumption that you meant that it was not flushing input buffers.  Perhaps you should post a separate question of your own?  However in the MS library [`flushall()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235367.aspx) is deprecated in favour of [`_flushall()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9xk9ehd.aspx).

Comment: @barlop : Good; however post a question next time - this is not the purpose of  comments on SO.  Posting a question you'll get a bigger audience and a faster answer as well as a adding a resource that is useful for all.  You are kind of lucky that two years after posting an answer to this question that I was even around to read your comment.

Answer (score 1):

[You should not fflush an input stream](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-57.html). The differences you observe came from the fact that the behaviour of this operations is undefined.

Comment: The link you provided and the related links have _some_ good advice, but at the same time they seem to be written by someone without a descent knowledge on C. Some of the statements are plain wrong or inaccurate at best. Be cautious.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are writing this program for Linux and believe it or not, `fflush(stdin)` only works under Windows. (That's at least what I got from my C book called C for dummies). The alternative for `fflush(stdin)` on Linux is `fpurge(stdin)`. Try it out and see if it works for you.