# How to check if input from stdin is null or newline

Tags: c, string, stdin

I am learning c and have written this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char message[100];
    FILE *secret=fopen(argv[1],"w");
    FILE *public=fopen(argv[2],"w");
    while(scanf("%99s\n",message)==1)
    {
        if (strcmp(message,"\n")) //this does not work as expected
            break;
        if(strstr(message,"secret"))
            fprintf(secret,"%s\n",message);
        else
            fprintf(public,"%s\n",message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program is expected to do this

1. accept two arguments from command line, which are names of two files
2. Create two files with pointers secret and public.
3. Read input from stdin
4. In a while loop

   1. If input is empty(null or newline), exit loop.
   2. if input contains phrase "secret", put the line into secret file.
   3. else put it into public file.

The problem is that the part of code to check if the input is empty is not working. The program does not exit on a empty input(i.e newline). What is the correct code?

BTW I read [How to check if stdin is empty in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20299348/3395716) but I did not understand anything.

Comment: Check the documentation for strcmp...

Comment: My `scanf` does not accept an empty line anyway. Even if it did, it would not contain a `newline`. I suggest `if (stricmp(message,"q"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blank line, enter only, should end this loop

```
while(scanf("%99[^\n]%*c",message)==1)
{
    if(strstr(message,"secret"))
        fprintf(secret,"%s\n",message);
    else
        fprintf(public,"%s\n",message);
}
```

Comment: This answer is awesome. Did not think this way.

Comment: What does `%*c` exactly do?` I guess it means "any number of characters, but at least 1". Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fgets` instead of `scanf` to read the string. `fgets` is not only secure against buffer overrun, it gives you leading `\n` character to test for empty lines.

```
while( fgets(message, sizeof message, stdin))
...    
  if( message[0] == '\n' ) break; /* Step 4.1 */
  str[ strlen(str) - 1 ] = '\0';  /* remove the newline before sending to the file */
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/RrgrNN)